# Implementing Comparator for a PriorityQueue. It functions with comparable and I can not understand what needs to change for Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I'll preface by saying that this is a project for a class. The logic of the code all functions and, as it stands, currently outputs close to the correct solution (I stopped working on the output when I learned that I had used the wrong interface). The problem is, the requirements very explicitly state we must use comparator. Being new to Java, I used Comparable, not realizing there was an explicit difference. This is an algorithms class in Java, my background is in Python and there are definitely some differences that are going over my head - I'm sure that will be apparent in my code.

I've sort of come to understand the difference between the two, but if you asked me to ELI5, I don't think I could. Please help me understand how exactly to implement Comparator as opposed to Comparable. I get that I need a separate class but then I'm not exactly sure how that should be formatted and what to do with it once I have it.

I'm including below the code of the working solution that implements comparable. Any guidance would be extremely appreciated. TIA.

EDIT: Also, by all means, anything else in particular about my code that stands out as going against Java conventions, I'm happy to hear about.

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ProcessScheduling {

    public static class Process implements Comparable<Process> {
        
        private Integer priority;
        private int id;
        private int arrivalTime;
        private int duration;

        public Process(int ID, Integer Priority, int Duration, int ArrivalTime) {
            this.id = ID;
            this.priority = Priority;
            this.duration = Duration;
            this.arrivalTime = ArrivalTime;
        }

        public Integer getPriority() {return priority;}
        public int getId() {return id;}
        public int getArrivalTime() {return arrivalTime;}
        public int getDuration() {return duration;}
        
        public void setPriority(Integer priority) {this.priority = priority;}

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Process ID = " + getId()
                + "\n\tPriority = " + getPriority()
                + "\n\tArrival = " + getArrivalTime()
                + "\n\tDuration = " + getDuration();
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Process P) {
            if (this.getPriority() > P.getPriority()) {return 1;}
            else if (this.getPriority() < P.getPriority()) {return -1;}
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create ArrayList D to store new processes
        ArrayList<Process> D = new ArrayList<Process>();
        // Read the input file
        try {
            File f = new File("process_scheduling_input.txt");
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(f);
            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                // Create new Processes and add them to ArrayList D
                String[] data = reader.nextLine().split(" ");
                Process newProcess = new Process(   Integer.valueOf(data[0]),
                                                    Integer.parseInt(data[1]),
                                                    Integer.parseInt(data[2]),
                                                    Integer.parseInt(data[3])
                );
                D.add(newProcess);
            }
            reader.close();
        }   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occured. File does not exist.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Print all processes
        for (int i = 0; i < D.size(); i++) {
            Process current = D.get(i);
            System.out.print("Id = " + current.getId());
            System.out.print(", priority = " + current.getPriority());
            System.out.print(", duration = " + current.getDuration());
            System.out.println(", arrival time = " + current.getArrivalTime());
        }

        // Instantiate priorityQueue and some parameters
        int currentTime = 10;
        boolean running = false;
        int maxWaitTime = 30;
        float totalWaitTime = 0;
        int currentEndTime = 0;
        Process current = null;
        PriorityQueue<Process> Q = new PriorityQueue<Process>();

        // Print maxWaitTime
        System.out.println("\nMaximum wait time = " + maxWaitTime);

        // While D still has a process in it
        while (D.isEmpty() == false) {
            // Check if current running process has finished
            if (running == true && currentEndTime <= currentTime) {
                // Print that Process finished
                System.out.print("Process " + current.getId());
                System.out.println(" finished at time " + currentTime + "\n");
                // Update running flag
                running = false;
                // Update priority of Processes in Q that have been waiting longer than max wait time
                System.out.println("Update priority:");
                if (Q.isEmpty() == false) {
                    for (Process p : Q) {
                        int waitTime = currentTime - p.getArrivalTime();
                        if (waitTime >= maxWaitTime) {
                            Integer priority = p.getPriority();
                            int id = p.getId();
                            System.out.print("PID = " + id);
                            System.out.print(", wait time = " + waitTime);
                            System.out.println(", current priority = " + priority);
                            priority -= 1;
                            p.setPriority(priority);
                            System.out.print("PID = " + id);
                            System.out.println(", new priority = " + priority);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Find process with earliest arrivalTime in D
            Process earliest = D.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < D.size(); i++) {
                if (D.get(i).getArrivalTime() < earliest.getArrivalTime()) {
                    earliest = D.get(i);
                }
            }
            // Check if arrivalTime of earliest is <= to currentTime
            if (earliest.getArrivalTime() <= currentTime) {
                // Add to Q and remove from D if yes
                Q.add(earliest);
                D.remove(earliest);
            }
            // Check if Q is not empty and running flag is false
            if (Q.isEmpty() == false && running == false) {
                // Remove process in Q with smallest priority
                current = Q.poll();
                int waitTime = currentTime - current.getArrivalTime();
                totalWaitTime += waitTime;
                currentEndTime = currentTime + current.getDuration();
                // Process removed from priority queue, print info
                System.out.print("\nProcess removed from queue is: id = " + current.getId());
                System.out.print(", at time " + currentTime);
                System.out.print(", wait time = " + waitTime);
                System.out.println(" Total wait time = " + totalWaitTime);
                System.out.println(current);
                running = true;
            }
            if (D.isEmpty() == true) {
                System.out.println("\nD becomes empty at time " + currentTime + "\n");
            }
            currentTime++;
        }

        // D is now empty, all processes are in Q
        while (Q.isEmpty() == false) {
            // Check if current running process has finished
            if (running == true && currentEndTime >= currentTime) {
                // Update running flag
                running = false;
                // Update priority of Processes in Q that have been waiting longer than max wait time
                System.out.println("Update priority:");
                if (Q.isEmpty() == false) {
                    for (Process p : Q) {
                        if (p.getArrivalTime() - currentTime >= maxWaitTime) {
                            p.priority = p.getPriority() - 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // If no Process running, start a new one
            if (running == false){
                current = Q.poll();
                int waitTime = currentTime - current.getArrivalTime();
                totalWaitTime += waitTime;
                currentEndTime = currentTime + current.getDuration();
                // Process removed from priority queue, print info
                System.out.print("\nProcess removed from queue is: id = " + current.getId());
                System.out.print(", at time " + currentTime);
                System.out.print(", wait time = " + waitTime);
                System.out.println(" Total wait time = " + totalWaitTime);
                System.out.println(current);
                running = true;
            }
            currentTime++;




            currentTime++;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where exactly does that go in the file? What is it nested under? I figured it's something very very close but my ignorance with Java means I'm struggling to actually know where that goes.

And it's an Integer because it's specified as such in the requirements for the assignment. I also had that question and the answer from the professor was something about Integer having more functionality to it. Considering what is being done here, I don't see why it's necessary though.

Comment: As noted by @BasilBourque, my initial comment contained a grievous error: the class that currently implements Comparable should no longer implement Comparable. The `Comparator<Process>` class is a new class, but since it is so very simple, a functional interface (since it only has one method), it is probably best created as a lambda / anonymous inner class: `new PriorityQueue<Process>((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.getPriority(), p2.getPriority()));`  You create it right where you call your `PriorityQueue` constructor.

Comment: Also: probably better to declare the priority field an int and not an Integer. Also, best to rename your Process class to another name that does not clash with a commonly used core Java class. Also, best to learn and follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), including giving fields names that start with a lower-case letter. This will help others (us!) to better understand your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of those things are requirements for the project. It is specified that the class be called "process" and it is specified that the priority field be an Integer.

Comment: I see. But it is *not* a requirement to give a field the name `Q`, I am sure. That field name should begin with a lower-case and should be much more informative and self-commenting.

Comment: Lol... nope... that one was also specified. And the ArrayList being named D. Yes... this professor's variable names drive me absolutely nuts.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest differences between `Comparator` and `Comparable` is that a `Comparator` can order objects of different classes.  `Comparable` generally can only order the same type of objects.

So, I'd say you're well on your way, it's not as big a jump as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Comparator.comparing( Process :: getPriority )
```

## Details

You said:

> how exactly to implement `Comparator` as opposed to `Comparable`. I get that I need a separate class

Yes, that is the difference, a separate class.

- Implementing [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) is done by adding a method `compareTo` within the  class of the objects being sorted. That means you are limited one single approach to sorting.
- Implementing [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) is done in a separate class. So we can more than one such `Comparator` implementation, for as many ways as we wish to sort our objects.

For example, a class `Student` representing people enrolled in a school might implement `Comparable` by adding a `compareTo` method that sorts by last name, and secondarily by first name. But in some contexts we might want to sort students by their grade level, and in other contexts by the date in which they first enrolled, and in yet other contexts we might sort by the distance between their home and the schoolhouse. For this other contexts we would write various classes implementing `Comparator`.

If you want to compare by a `getPriority` method that returns an `int` primitive, then your separate `Comparator` class might look like this.

```
class ProcessByPriorityComparator implements Comparator< Process > {  
    public int compare( Process p1 , Process p2 ){  
        if( p1.getPriority() == p2.getPriority() )  
        {
            return 0;  
        } 
        else if ( p1.getPriority() > p1.getPriority() )
        {
            return 1;  
        }
        else  
        { 
            return -1;  
        }  
    }
}
```

Or simplify:

```
class ProcessByPriorityComparator implements Comparator< Process > {  
    public int compare( Process p1 , Process p2 ){  
        return Integer.compare( p1.getPriority() , p2.getPriority() ) ;  
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
Comparator< Process > processByPriorityComparator = 
        new ProcessByPriorityComparator() ;
Collections.sort( listOfProcesses , processByPriorityComparator ) ;
```

Or simply:

```
Collections.sort( listOfProcesses , new ProcessByPriorityComparator() ) ;
```

The lambda functional functional features in Java makes it quite easy to define a `Comparator` locally rather than formally defining a separate class.

Greatly helping to simplify this work are the static methods on `Comparator` such as `comparing`. So defining a `Comparator` can be as simple as using a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) for an [accessor “getter” method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#Java) to sort by a particular property of the object.

This is quite appropriate in your particular case. We can use a method reference for the `Process#getPriority` method.

```
Comparator< Process > processByPriorityComparator = 
        Comparator.comparing( Process :: getPriority );
Collections.sort( listOfProcesses , processByPriorityComparator ) ;
```

Or, more simply, drop the named variable holding the comparator.

```
Collections.sort( listOfProcesses , Comparator.comparing( Process :: getPriority ) )
```

---

By the way, other issues with your code…

Do yourself a favor and move that huge `main` method out to its own class. Create a separate class named something like `Main` or `App`.

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        …
    }
}
```

And I see no need for `Process` to be `static` nor be nested.

I suspect you feel some compulsion to have everything squeezed into a single class or file. Not so in Java. In Java you should generally have many classes, smaller and separate.

Eventually, as your app grows, organize the many classes by using packages and possible modules.

Comment: Yea, thats exactly what I mean by my inexperience with Java was going to be apparent. I've written a grand total of 5 java programs, most of which were just "implement the methods that this main method calls." This is the first one that's entirely from scratch and is the project for the class.

Comment: Wow, I clearly need a better understanding of how to structure Java programs. I just went and tried to make a main.java file but it wants the signature to be "public class main" not "public static void main(string[] args)". I'm sure the answer is obvious to someone who knows Java but the idiosyncrasies are driving me nuts.

I also think I might be missing something about how VSCode wants Java files organized. I'm concerned it just isn't recognizing my second file with the comparator method in it. IDK.